# why sum of digits $(a+b)$ = sum of digits of $(a)$ + sum of digits of $(b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

eg:

Sum of digits $(12+14)$ = sum of digits $(26)$ = $8$

sum of digits of $(12)$ = $3$
sum of digits of $(14)$ = $5$
adding these gives $8$

How this can be proved mathematically?

Will this be true for all integers (positive and negative)?

**EDIT**: We need to repeatedly find sum of digits as given below

```
  Sum of digits (9+1)=Sum of digits (10)=1

    sum of digits (9)=9, 
    sum of digits (1)=1

adding gives 10, again, sum of digits of 10 gives 1,
```

Comment: This is wrong! Try 9 + 1!

Comment: You probably mean digit sum which is different from sum of digits.

Comment: l actually meant what @Atrthur mentioned. for eg, sum of digits of (9+1)=10=1 ; 1+0 gives same

Comment: Do you mean [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root)?

Comment: yes, i meant digital root, i was not aware of this before. Now got to know thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to refer to the [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) instead?

Call the digital root of $x$ as the function $dr(x)$.

Then
$$dr(a + b) \equiv \left(dr(a) + dr(b)\right) \pmod 9$$
so that your claim follows.

Comment: yes, i didnot know this term. I meant the same and this property was noticed by me while my studies. I will learn it now. thx

Comment: so for digital root, is this true always?

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample:

sum of digits (9)=9

sum of digits (1)=1

sum of digits (9+1)=(10)=1

$9+1\neq 1$

Your algorithm only works if you don't have carry-overs...

Comment: Sorry, if i was not clear. What I meant is, sum of digits (9)=9, sum of digits (1)=1, adding gives 10, again, sum of digits of 10 gives 1.

Answer (score 0):

Sum of digits of $999999999$ is $81$.

Sum of digits of $1$ is $1$.

Sum of digits of the sum $1000000000$ is $1$.

$81+1 = 82$.  Sum of its digits is $10$. Sum of its digits is $1$.

Is that what you mean?  Keep doing it until you have a single digit?

Comment: yes, this is exactly i meant. thx. through one of the answer given, i see this is digital root, right?

Answer (score 0):

@kiran this is just property of numbers. Digital sum & digital roots are the same & a/C to your question I think you are asking for digital root. So friend this is powerful technique invented by our ancient great mathematicians.

Comment: thx a lot. i was not knowing these terms. Now it is clear.

Comment: Bro one new name T9 method. This also called to this method